# Python - numpy.loadtxt how to ignore end commas?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to read in a file that looks like this:

```
1, 2,
3, 4,
```

I'm using the following line:

```
l1,l2 = numpy.loadtxt('file.txt',unpack=True,delimiter=', ')
```

This gives me an error because the end comma in each row is lumped together as the last element (e.g. "2" is read as "2,"). Is there a way to ignore the last comma in each row, with loadtxt or another function?

Comment: Any reason your data are stored like that?

Comment: The file was written by someone else, so I have to deal with it.

Comment: Bummer. Why not preprocess it python or sed or awk or ...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) is a bit more robust.  If you use the default dtype (which is `np.float64`), it thinks there is a third column with missing values, so it creates a third column containing `nan`.  If you give it `dtype=None` (which tells it to figure out the data type from the file), it returns a third column containing all zeros.  Either way, you can ignore the last column by using `usecols=[0, 1]`:

```
In [14]: !cat trailing_comma.csv
1, 2,
3, 4,
```

Important note: I use `delimiter=','`, not `delimiter=', '`.

```
In [15]: np.genfromtxt('trailing_comma.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, usecols=[0,1])
Out[15]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [16]: col1, col2 = np.genfromtxt('trailing_comma.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, usecols=[0,1], unpack=True)

In [17]: col1
Out[17]: array([1, 3])

In [18]: col2
Out[18]: array([2, 4])
```

Comment: `usecols` is great for a small number of columns. Otherwise, it gets very tedious. For large numbers of columns, it's easier to read everything in (including the last column of 0 or None) and then truncate the data with `data = data[:, 0:-1]`. That is all rows and all columns except for the last.

Answer (score 3):

`usecols` also works with `loadtxt`:

Simulate a file with text split into lines:

```
In [162]: txt=b"""1, 2,
3,4,"""
In [163]: txt=txt.splitlines()
In [164]: txt
Out[164]: [b'1, 2,', b'3,4,']

In [165]: x,y=np.loadtxt(txt,delimiter=',',usecols=[0,1],unpack=True)
In [166]: x
Out[166]: array([ 1.,  3.])
In [167]: y
Out[167]: array([ 2.,  4.])
```

`loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` don't work well with multicharacter delimiters.

`loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` accept any iterable, including a generator.  Thus you could open the file and process the lines one by one, removing the extra character.

```
In [180]: def g(txt):
   .....:     t = txt.splitlines()
   .....:     for l in t:
   .....:         yield l[:-1]

In [181]: list(g(txt))
Out[181]: [b'1, 2', b'3,4']
```

A generator that yields the lines one by one, stripped of the last character.  This could be changed to read a file line by line:

```
In [182]: x,y=np.loadtxt(g(txt),delimiter=',',unpack=True)
In [183]: x,y
Out[183]: (array([ 1.,  3.]), array([ 2.,  4.]))
```

Comment: Ah, that's good to know.  I should have tried `usecols` in `loadtxt` before I jumped to `genfromtxt`.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs this solution might be overkill but when working with large sets of data files from external sources (especially excel, but also binary, csv, tsv, or others) I found the `pandas` module to be a very convenient and efficient way to read and process data.

Given a data file `test-data.txt` having the following content

```
1, 2,
2, 3,
4, 5,
```

you can read the file by using

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("test-data.txt", names = ("col1", "col2"), usecols=(0,1))
in[25]: data
Out[25]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     2     3
2     4     5
In[26]: data.col1
Out[26]: 
0    1
1    2
2    4
```

The result is a `DataFrame` object with indexed lines and column labels that can be used for data access. If your data file contains a header it is directly used for labeling the columns. Otherwise you can specify the label for each column with the `names` argument. The `usecols` argument allows to avoid the 3rd column that would otherwise be read as a column with `nan` values.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a solution that:

1. doesn't require manually specifying columns (as accepted answer)
2. doesn't use different packages (e.g. pandas)
3. doesn't require preprocessing
4. dynamically works for inputs with and without trailing commas (without specifying)

I went with using numpy.genfromtxt instead, overwriting its delimiting behaviour to ignore the last element if it's empty:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib import npyio


def _cutoff_last(func, *args, **kwargs) -> list:
    line = func(*args, **kwargs)
    if line and line[-1] == '':
        line = line[:-1]
    return line


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # overwrite delimiting behavior
    _delim_splitter_original = npyio.LineSplitter._delimited_splitter
    npyio.LineSplitter._delimited_splitter = lambda *args: _cutoff_last(_delim_splitter_original, *args)

    mat = np.genfromtxt('mat.txt', delimiter=',')
```

This probably should not be used in large code-bases (as it changes the behaviour of numpy), but is perfect for many use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to roll your own file-reader in Python, rather than having to rely on the constraints of `numpy.loadtxt`:

```
content = [ [ float( x ) for x in row.split(',') if x.strip() ] for row in open( filename, 'rt' ) ]
```

Comment: But when `numpy` is used, one is usually dealing with (relatively) large files. Then, a specialised reader like numpy's is often more efficient. Also, you should use a contextmanager with `open`, in order not to rely on reference counting to close your file, which technically is an implementation detail.